# Simplify SQL Query to look in a list

Tags: sql

I have a query like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Filename = "abc.exe" OR Filename = "test.txt" OR Filename = "def.exe" .... OR
```

Is there a way to simplify this to be 'cleaner' where i can say `WHERE Filename = ("abc.exe", "test.txt", "def.exe", ...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `IN` operator instead of multiple `OR` conditions. With `=` you cannot compare more than one value

```
where Filename in ("abc.exe","test.txt","def.exe",..)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make use of the `IN` clause, which checks if a value is one of the specified candidates.

Example:

```
WHERE Filename IN ("abc.exe","test.txt","def.exe")
```